# Would you like to join us on Slack?

Tags: discussion

Tom Simm recently posted on the SDL Community about the possibility of an SDL Slack and it turns out there isn’t one out there yet (other than the MVP Slack). I thought this was a great idea as I know a lot of useful conversations go on in the MVP Slack (it’s not just about secret MVP things).

I also know that there are a lot of knowledgeable people out there in the SDL Web community that aren’t MVP’s and it would be great to gather all these like minded people together. So after a quick discussion with Rob Stevenson-Legett, Chris Morgan and Tom Simm we are pleased to announce the grand opening of the SDL Web Slack team!

We’ve added channels for all the different products (#tridion, #smarttarget, #dxa) as well as #tds2017 which is for chatting about the up and coming Tridion Developer Summit.

In order to join we just need you to [fill in this quick Google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfYDStZl_p0GrZ-D6Srdi_eU4aXbnIRMqglRN5_tT6VXNUx1A/viewform?usp=sf_link) which explains the guidelines of the community and then one of us will send you the link.